# How amcl works?

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server, amcl, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I use this file:

```
<launch>
<!-- Run the map server -->
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server"
args="$(find robot_setup_tf)/mymaps/map.yaml" output="screen"/>

<include file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/amcl_diff.launch">
</include>

<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
<rosparam file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
</node>

<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d rviz_cfg.rviz"/>

</launch>
```

but what amcl would do? Because I see the map and what laser scan see but nothing happens. I think it should overlap the scan points on the map, is it correct? Thanks you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229978/how-amcl-works?/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-03-23

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL tries to match the laser scans to the map thus detecting if there is any drift occurring in the pose estimate based on the odometry (dead reckoning). This drift is then compensated by publishing a transform between the map frame and the odom frame such that at the end the transform map->base_frame corresponds to the real pose of the robot in the world. It is explained [here](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) with a nice diagram:

[image description http://wiki.ros.org/amcl?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=amcl_localization.png](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=amcl_localization.png)

[here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) you can find the definitions and uses of each frame for ROS REP105 naming conventions:

> **Coordinate Frames**

> **map**

> The coordinate frame called map is a
> world fixed frame, with its Z-axis
> pointing upwards. The pose of a mobile
> platform, relative to the map frame,
> should not significantly drift over
> time. The map frame is not continuous,
> meaning the pose of a mobile platform
> in the map frame can change in
> discrete jumps at any time.
>
> In a typical setup, a localization
> component constantly re-computes the
> robot pose in the map frame based on
> sensor observations, therefore
> eliminating drift, but causing
> discrete jumps when new sensor
> information arrives.
>
> The map frame is useful as a long-term
> global reference, but discrete jumps
> make it a poor reference frame for
> local sensing and acting.
>
> **odom**
>
> The coordinate frame called odom is a
> world-fixed frame. The pose of a
> mobile platform in the odom frame can
> drift over time, without any bounds.
> This drift makes the odom frame
> useless as a long-term global
> reference. However, the pose of a
> robot in the odom frame is guaranteed
> to be continuous, meaning that the
> pose of a mobile platform in the odom
> frame always evolves in a smooth way,
> without discrete jumps.
>
> In a typical setup the odom frame is
> computed based on an odometry source,
> such as wheel odometry, visual
> odometry or an inertia measurement
> unit.
>
> The odom frame is useful as an
> accurate, short-term local reference,
> but drift makes it a poor frame for
> long-term reference.
>
> **base_link**
>
> The coordinate frame called base_link
> is rigidly attached to the mobile
> robot base. The base_link can be
> attached to the base in any arbitrary
> position or orientation; for every
> hardware platform there will be a
> different place on the base that
> provides an obvious point of
> reference. Note that REP 103 [1]
> specifies a preferred orientation for
> frames.
>
> **Relationship between Frames**
>
> We have chosen a tree representation
> to attach all coordinate frames in a
> robot system to each other. Therefore
> each coordinate frame has one parent
> coordinate frame, and any number of
> child coordinate frames. The frames
> described in this REP are attached as
> follows:
>
> map --> odom --> base_link
>
> The map frame is the parent of odom,
> and odom is the parent of base_link.
> Although intuition would say that both
> map and odom should be attached to
> base_link, this is not allowed because
> each frame can only have one parent.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-03-28**:
@Mehdi. Hello, sir. Does the `real pose of the robot in the world` mentioned in your answer means that the real pose of the robot measured by a sensor such as lidar?

**Comment by [Vignesht.tech](https://answers.ros.org/users/65370/vignesht.tech/) on 2023-07-11**:
Yes he mentioned about the pose which localization gives you by matching laser scan with map